# How to resolve this message, Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch `eqnum'

Tags: horizontal-alignment, elsarticle, microtype

While using elsarticle-num.tex, I tried to disable hyphenation and make text in justifying alignment (horizontal-alignment) as MS-Word. `\usepackage{microtype}` is fine to make less hyphenation, there is a warning message like this:

> Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch `eqnum'

How to resolve this message? or is it fine to ignore?

Comment: you can ignore it. You can suppress the warning by using the package option nopatch with some value, see the documentation.

Comment: if you'd provide a MWE (or at least your preamble) this could be fixed.